# how to declare and initialize an integer variable

Tags: c, variables, assembly, integer, initialization

I want to declare some variables in MIPS(Assembly) and initialize them.I am parsing a C file.I initialize the variables like this:

```
.data

.text
.globl main

    .align 2
a:      .space 4

main:

#Exit
li $v0,10
syscall
```

But i don't know how to initialze variable a.I tried to use li,la,add,addi  etc but nothing worked right. 
I want my program to remember the value of the variable a.What if i have 5 or 10 variables?
What i mean o remember  is something like this(in C):

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
a=10;
b=10;
c=a+b;
b=b-5;
d=b+c;
e=d+a;
printf("e value is %d\n",e);
```

That's what i mean by remembering values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
main:
  #...
  la $a0, a
  li $a1, 1234 # The value you need
  sw $a1, 0($a0)
  #...
```

Also, your variables must be in the .data section:

```
.data

.align 2
a: .space 4

.text
# ...
```

Comment: But how can my program remember the value of variable a?

Comment: From one execution to the next one? You need to store in an external device, like a file